# What is a clean way to call a function within the database (PostgreSQL) from within an ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a function in the database called `pathname` that takes an `id` and returns the full path.  The ActiveRecord model is called `Dirent`.  So, my first attempt is:

```rb
  def pathname
    @pathname ||= Dirent.select("pathname(id) AS pn").where(id: self.id).first.pn
  end
```

(it memoizes the result).  Which works but I'm wondering if there are cleaner ways to do this.  (This is a ruby project using ActiveRecord but not Ruby on Rails.)

Comment: i am not sure, what you are asking, ruby can't know the function, so your approach  is correcct, what would you expect?

Comment: `self.id` -> `id`. It's cleaner :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "cleaner" (since that is a stylistic opinion). You could use `Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('pathname',[Arel.sql('id')]).as('pn')` which in my opinion is preferable but I am not sure I would call it cleaner. Another note is that you could use `pluck` to avoid the need to instantiate a malformed `Dirent` object e.g. `Dirent.pluck(Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('pathname',[Arel.sql('id')]).as('pn')).where(id: id).first`